# python pandas create dataframe winning streak

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools, pandas-groupby, cumsum

I need to create 'winning streak' columns.
For example, 
I have data like below. The column having the maximum value is the winner.

```
AA      BB      CC
5.95    5.95    0
0       -2.35   2.35
-0.6    -0.6    -0.6
-2.35   2.35    0
-1.6    1.6     -1.6
-1.25   1.25    1.25
1.85    0       -1.85
1.3     0       -1.3
-1.7    1.7     -1.7
0       0.25    0.25
```

and need to create "winning streak; how many times win cosecutively" columns of each like below.

```
AA      BB      CC      CW_AA   CW_BB   CW_CC
5.95    5.95    0       1       1       0
0       -2.35   2.35    0       0       1
-0.6    -0.6    -0.6    1       1       2
-2.35   2.35    0       0       2       0
-1.6    1.6     -1.6    0       3       0
-1.25   1.25    1.25    0       4       1
1.85    0       -1.85   1       0       0
1.3     0       -1.3    2       0       0
-1.7    1.7     -1.7    0       1       0
0       0.25    0.25    0       2       1
```

I've tried to make it using "itertools" library (groupby) but can't yet.
Anyone could help me please?

```
pd.DataFrame({'AA':[5.95, 0, -0.6, -2.35, -1.6, -1.25, 1.85, 1.3, -1.7, 0],
        'BB':[5.95, -2.35, -0.6, 2.35, 1.6, 1.25, 0, 0, 1.7, 0.25],
        'CC':[0, 2.35, -0.6, 0, -1.6, 1.25, -1.85, -1.3, -1.7, 0.25]})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
a = df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)
b = a.cumsum()
df = b - b.where(~a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   AA  BB  CC
0   1   1   0
1   0   0   1
2   1   1   2
3   0   2   0
4   0   3   0
5   0   4   1
6   1   0   0
7   2   0   0
8   0   1   0
9   0   2   1
```

**Explanation**:

1. First compare all columns by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with `max` per rows
2. Count consecutive `True`s by subtract cumulative sums by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)

Comment: Thanks again! Yeah, that's exactly what I wanted!